# Mupdf library not working properly on some devices

Tags: android, mupdf

I have integrated mupdf library in my project. it is working perfectly fine but not on some samsung devices. can you please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

This is because mupdf library doesnt support some mobile os architectures

Comment: Which mobile OS architectures?

Answer (score 0):

As some phone only allow to run 32 bit libraries so you have to disable 64 for your application but this will also create an issue because if you disable 64 then the phone which  require 64 bit libraries wont run. Its a bug which is not resolved in the mupdf release